# Can `Iterator` be used unrelated to `Iterable` both directly and indirectly?

Tags: java

In Java

- is `Iterator` always used with `Iterable` ?
- Is `Iterator` instance always created or obtained directly or indirectly via `Iterable.iterator()` method?
- Can `Iterator` be used unrelated to `Iterable` both directly and indirectly?

Comment: Streams do not implement `Iterable`, but [they provide iterators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/BaseStream.html#iterator--).

Answer (score 3):

`Iterator` doesn't have to always be used with `Iterable`, but usually they are used together.

An `Iterator` instance can be created without using `Iterable.iterator()` method, as long as the class implementing the `Iterator` interface has access to the structure that holds the elements to be iterated over.

An `Iterator` can be used unrelated to `Iterable`. There is nothing stopping you from creating a class that implements the `Iterator` interface, and start iterating over that `Iterator`.

That said, `Iterable` serves as a factory to produce new `Iterator` instances suitable for iterating over some group of elements. Therefore it makes sense to use them together.

Instead of having a class `MyContainer<Element>` and an independent `MyContainerIter<Element> implements Iterator<Element>`, it is often useful to have `MyContainer<Element> implements Iterable<Element>`, and have the implementation of the `Iterator` as an inner class. This allows the `Iterator` implementation to access non-public members of the class containing the elements you wish to iterate over.

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr** `Iterator` can be used without `Iterable`, but they are much better together.

> is `Iterator` always used with `Iterable`?

Not at all: nothing in the library makes this a requirement.

> Is `Iterator` instance always created or obtained directly or indirectly via `Iterable.iterator()` method?

No. `Iterator` is only an interface, you can produce instances of classes that implement it anywhere in your code.

> Can `Iterator` be used unrelated to `Iterable` both directly and indirectly?

Absolutely. `Iterable` is a factory of `Iterator` objects, but it's not the only way to obtain these objects.

This said, there is a great deal of convenience to be had if you do implement `Iterable`, and use it to make your `Iterator` instances with the `iterator()` method. This is because enhanced `for` loop in Java is built around `Iterable`: you cannot feed it a "raw" iterator directly, but giving it an `Iterable` produces a short-looking loop that hides a lot of API calls for you. In fact, enhanced `for` loop lets you hide both `Iterator` and `Iterable` behind an easy-to-read sequencing construct.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use `Iterator`s without implementing `Iterable`. But there's rarely any point in doing so. You wouldn't be able to use foreach loops for example.

Answer (score 0):

> - is `Iterator` always used with `Iterable` ?

**Yes** - the definition of `Iterable` is:

```
public interface Iterable<T> {
    Iterator<T> iterator();
}
```

> - Is `Iterator` instance always created or obtained directly or indirectly via `Iterable.iterator()` method?

**No** you can create your own `Iterator` without an `Iterable`.

```
Iterator<Integer> iter = new Iterator<Integer>() {
    private int n;
    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Integer next() {
        return n++;
    }
};
```

> - Can `Iterator` be used unrelated to `Iterable` both directly and indirectly?

**Yes** - see above.